# Which formula for elastic collision?

Tags: physics

When researching a bit about elastic collisions, I've been confused about how many different ways there are to do this. I've seen multiple methods, some of which are extremely complex (using sine and cosine) and some which are more simple.

For example, this [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/345863/10350056) provides a simple solution, while this [tutplus article](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/playing-around-with-elastic-collisions--active-7472) uses a more complex solution.

I'm trying to make a simple simulation which there are balls that bouncing around borders and other balls. What formula should I use and what are the differences between them?

Comment: For frictionless elastic collision, all follows from energy and momentum conservation and the direction of the force ...

Comment: There is more than one way to calculate anything. The tutplus site worked out the physics according to the knowledge of the programmer, and once they found a solution, they implemented it. The stack overflow answer was one where they went farther and simplified the answer as far as they could, looking in particular for something easy to program. I'd go with it myself.